# Path Expected for Join! Nhibernate Error

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I trying to do a join and I keep getting this error

> Path expected for join! [SELECT
>   t.CourseId FROM  Task as t INNER JOIN
>   Courses as c, CoursePermissions as cp
>   WHERE (t.CourseId = 1)]

I have

```
const string query = "SELECT t.CourseId FROM  Task as t INNER JOIN Courses as c, CoursePermissions as cp WHERE (t.CourseId = 1)";

var a = session.CreateQuery(query);
```

My Sql I am trying to achieve

```
SELECT     dbo.Tasks.CourseId
FROM         dbo.Tasks INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Courses ON dbo.Tasks.CourseId = dbo.Courses.CourseId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.CoursePermissions ON dbo.Courses.CourseId = dbo.CoursePermissions.CourseId
WHERE     (dbo.Tasks.CourseId = 1)
```

I am using nhibernate 3.1 and fluent nhibernate 1.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means that you using an inner join in HQL works a little different than using it in SQL. In HQL you join the tables by providing the "path", which is basically the referenced property of your class.

So instead of

```
SELECT t.CourseId FROM Task as t INNER JOIN Courses as c ...
```

you need to write

```
// c.Taks is the IList property in your Courses class
SELECT t.CourseId FROM Courses as c INNER JOIN c.Tasks as t ...
```

Comment: does this work if you don't have a foreign key on Task table?

Answer (score 0):

Although Florian Lim has suggested a great solution but in my case I didn't had **IList** for Tasks in Courses. I achieved that through [Theta-Style Joins](https://lishman.io/joins-in-hibernate-query-language) which actually is [Cartesian product](http://db.grussell.org/co22001%20notes_files/image126.gif) provide all possible combinations which can be filtered (in where clause) according to need.