# join query for two tables in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I need an InnerJoin Query in HCQL for following native SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN registered_users 
WHERE user.id=registered_users.user_id;
```

I need the result as list of user objects.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379766/hql-hibernate-inner-join this can help

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Answer (score 0):

You can use HQL like this :

```
SELECT U FROM User U INNER JOIN U.registeredUsers RU;
```

Or you can use native sql like this :

```
SELECT U.* FROM user U INNER JOIN registered_users RU WHERE U.id=RU.user_id;
```

I will prefer you to use HQL.