# HQL : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I trying to do a join and I keep getting this error

**I have**

```
SELECT a.uidsgn, a.uname, a.ubatid, a.uloc, a.dpcodu , a.smbrch
FROM Fefusr AS a
LEFT JOIN Ssfuser AS b ON a.uidsgn = b.ssuidsgn
LEFT JOIN Ssfgroup AS c ON b.ssgrpid = c.ssgrpid
LEFT JOIN Ssfuserchg AS d ON a.uidsgn = d.ssuidsgn AND d.statusaut <> '1'
    AND d.ssidmenu = 'LOC'
WHERE a.smbrch = '1' AND b.ssuidsgn <> 'BK20151101'
    AND a.nextp NOT IN('JWPLOGON, ATM01C')
ORDER BY d.ssuidsgn
```

**And this error Warning**

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for
>   join! [SELECT a.uidsgn, a.uname, a.ubatid, a.uloc, a.dpcodu , a.smbrch
>   FROM bukiweb.entity.Fefusr AS a  LEFT JOIN Ssfuser AS b ON a.uidsgn =
>   b.ssuidsgn  LEFT JOIN Ssfgroup AS c ON b.ssgrpid = c.ssgrpid  LEFT
>   JOIN Ssfuserchg AS d  ON a.uidsgn = d.ssuidsgn AND d.statusaut <> '1'
>   AND d.ssidmenu = 'LOC'  WHERE a.smbrch = '1' AND b.ssuidsgn <>
>   'BK20151101' AND a.nextp NOT IN('JWPLOGON, ATM01C') ORDER BY
>   d.ssuidsgn]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HQL ERROR: Path expected for join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448935/hql-error-path-expected-for-join)

Comment: Which Hibernate version you use?