# How to resolve Path expected for join in JPA Spring boot

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am receiving

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!

Error in JPA Spring boot kindly let me know what is the issue in following query

```
 select q.label, 
 q.id, q.parentId, 
 c.id , c.createdOn,
 c.logAnswerVisualData, 
 c.logAnswerValue, 
 a.label, 
 a.typeId, 
 a.visualTypeId, 
 vt.label, 
(SELECT Count(pq.id) FROM Pinnedquestion pq WHERE 
pq.questionId = q.id  AND pq.userId =:userId), 
(SELECT Count(fq.id) FROM Favoritequestion fq WHERE 
fq.questionId = q.id  AND fq.userId =:userId), 
at.label FROM Question q JOIN Conversation c ON q.id = 
c.questionId JOIN Answer a ON  a.id = q.answerId JOIN AnswerType at ON  
at.id = a.typeId LEFT JOIN VisualizationType vt ON vt.id = a.visualTypeId 
WHERE  c.userId =:userId AND c.id=:convId ORDER BY c.serverTimestamp desc
```

Comment: I assume You are talking abot Spring Data JPA used in Spring Boot. This query is created by hand or is the result of criteria query or Spring Data DSL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HQL ERROR: Path expected for join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448935/hql-error-path-expected-for-join)

Comment: JPQL syntax is shown in many docs on the web. You seem to be attempting to join to some unrelated entity whereas you should join through relations. So you resolve it by doing just that (or looking at documentation ...)

Comment: do you guys have any example code in which I can see a proper solution

Comment: How can anyone give "an example" when you don't post your entities and show the relations? There are lots of JPQL docs on the web